# updating rows on table 1 based on data from table2

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Need some help with a query to update certain columns of the table1  based on a field of table 2 if another field of table 1 and table2 matches.

I want to update the id(1234 and 7891) of tbl 1 with ids (4321 and 1987 respectively) of tbl2 if the ids are not same but loc1 and loc2 are same and upd is Y in tbl2.

```
     tbl1                                      tbl2

id   loc1    loc2                 id       loc1   loc2    upd
1234  a1     b1                   4321      a1     b1      Y
4567  a2     b2                   4567      a2     b2
7891  a3     b3                   1987      a3     b3      Y
3456  a4     b4                   6543      a4     b4
```

Comment: You can user MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MERGE INTO tbl1 e
    USING tbl2 h
    ON (e.loc1 = h.loc1 and e.loc2=h.loc2 and h.upd='Y')
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.id = h.id;
```

You can leave the not matched clause.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the id(1234 and 7891) of tbl 1 with ids (4321 and 1987 respectively) of tbl2 if the ids are not same but loc1 and loc2 are same and upd is Y in tbl2.

You could use **MERGE** with only **UPDATE** option. If you are on Oracle `version 10g` and up, the **MATCHED** and **NOT MATCHED** clauses are **optional**.

**Table data**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

        ID LO LO
---------- -- --
      1234 a1 b1
      4567 a2 b2
      7891 a3 b3
      3456 a4 b4

SQL> SELECT * FROM t2;

        ID LO LO U
---------- -- -- -
      4321 a1 b1
      4567 a2 b2
      1987 a3 b3
      6543 a4 b4
```

Now, let's **MERGE** `t2` **USING** `t1`:

```
SQL> MERGE INTO t2 s
  2  USING      t1 d
  3  ON        (s.loc1 = d.loc1
  4        AND  s.loc2 = d.loc2)
  5    WHEN MATCHED THEN
  6       UPDATE SET s.upd = 'Y'
  7     WHERE s.ID <> d.ID;

3 rows merged.
```

Let's verify table T2 data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t2;

        ID LO LO U
---------- -- -- -
      4321 a1 b1 Y
      4567 a2 b2
      1987 a3 b3 Y
      6543 a4 b4 Y
```

So, three rows in table T2 have been updated with `UPD` = `'Y'`.

I assume you want to update the `upd` column with value `Y` based on the condition. If you want to update some other column, then just change the column name in the **ON** and **WHERE** clause.